# Bad lib references building FFmpeg after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: compiling, 22.04, ffmpeg

I have a custom FFmpeg build, with custom filters, built from the FFmpeg master branch.
It's working fine in 20.04, on several machines.
However, when I tried to run it on my personal machine, updated from 20.04 to 22.04 a few weeks ago, I got this error:

```sh
$ ./ffmpeg 
./ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libvpx.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The obvious reason for that is the need to recompile it using new headers from new packages pointing to new versions of the libs. Which I did. However, no matter how many times I recompiled it, it always ends up looking for the same old versions of the libs.

Here's a list of libs not working in my build process:

```sh
$ ldd ./ffmpeg | grep not
    libvpx.so.6 => not found
    libwebp.so.6 => not found
    libcodec2.so.0.9 => not found
    libx264.so.155 => not found
    libx265.so.179 => not found
```

All of them have newer versions installed:

```sh
$ find /usr/ -name "libvpx.so*" -or -name "libwebp.so*" -or -name "libcodec2.so*" -or -name "libx264.so*" -or -name "libx265.so*"  2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.7.1.3
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.7
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.163
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcodec2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.79
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5.0.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x264-10bit/libx264.so.148
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.7.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.7.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcodec2.so.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.7
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.7.1.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.7
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.199
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.148
```

So far, I've tried:

1. Obviously re-configure and re-compile.
2. Deleting all binaries from build dir, as well as looking for direct hard-coded references to lib versions (which I didn't find).
3. Cloning the repo on a clean directory, with the same configuration flags but no custom code.

In all cases, the build is successful, but the binary files have references to those non-existent libraries. My configuration flags are all `--enable-libstuff` for different libs, as is normal when setting up some build, and do not have explicit versioning.

I don't see anybody online having this problem, so I suppose maybe some local issue. But I don't understand what it could be, as I don't have those versions hardcoded anywhere.

So, my question is: **what could be affecting my build in Ubuntu 22.04, that ends up behaving this way?**

Answer (score 2):

For anybody getting this issue: it was the shared libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, built months ago, before the update. The newer compilations did build everything fine, but I wasn't running `sudo make install` in order to deploy the newer shared libs. So, the newer executable was trying to use the older shared libs, which in turn indeed pointed to now non existant libs.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had ffmpeg issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04, and had the libvpx.so.6 problem.

`apt-cache` only shows v7:

```
$ apt-cache search libvpx
libvpx-dev - VP8 and VP9 video codec (development files)
libvpx-doc - VP8 and VP9 video codec (API documentation)
libvpx7 - VP8 and VP9 video codec (shared library)
```

To find the older debs, I just went to the debian package search, e.g.

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libvpx&searchon=names

Here it shows a bunch of old stuff:

[image]

I found most of my dependencies to be part of `bullseye`, so just click on the bullseye/stable link, then click on e.g. amd64 (or whatever your architecture is):

[image]

Then click on a mirror, e.g. `http.us.debian.org/debian`

Once downloaded, install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libvpx6_1.8.2-1build1_amd64.deb
```

Others I had to do:

- libdav1d4
- libx264-160
- libx265-192

...the finally `ffmpeg -codecs` ran with some output.

(Oh, and then Firefox could also start playing ALL videos on Youtube, not just *some* of them.)